# How to interrupt a thread performing a blocking socket connect?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, interrupt, system-calls

I have some code that spawns a `pthread` that attempts to maintain a socket connection to a remote host. If the connection is ever lost, it attempts to reconnect using a blocking `connect()` call on its socket. Since the code runs in a separate thread, I don't really care about the fact that it uses the synchronous socket API.

That is, until it comes time for my application to exit. I would like to perform some semblance of an orderly shutdown, so I use thread synchronization primitives to wake up the thread and signal for it to exit, then perform a `pthread_join()` on the thread to wait for it to complete. This works great, unless the thread is in the middle of a `connect()` call when I command the shutdown. In that case, I have to wait for the connect to time out, which could be a long time. This makes the application appear to take a long time to shut down.

What I would like to do is to interrupt the call to `connect()` in some way. After the call returns, the thread will notice my exit signal and shut down cleanly. Since `connect()` is a system call, I thought that I might be able to intentionally interrupt it using a signal (thus making the call return `EINTR`), but I'm not sure if this is a robust method in a POSIX threads environment.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this, either using signals or via some other method? As a note, the `connect()` call is down in some library code that I cannot modify, so changing to a non-blocking socket is not an option.

Comment: Please also put a language tag.

Comment: I'm actually writing in Python, but I'm not looking for anything language-specific. You can assume that I'm operating on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to *close()* the socket to interrupt the *connect()*. I'm not sure, but I think it will work at least on Linux. Of course, be careful to synchronize properly such that you only ever *close()* this socket once, or a second *close()* could theoretically close an unrelated file descriptor that was just opened.

**EDIT**: *shutdown*() might be more appropriate because it does not actually close the socket.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at [pthread_cancel()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) and [pthread_kill()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html). However, I don't see a way to use these two without a race condition.

I advise that you abandon the multithreaded-server approach and instead go event-driven, for example by using [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) for event notification. This way you can avoid all these very basic problems that become very hard with threads, like proper shutdown. You are free to at any time do anything you want, e.g. safely close sockets and never hear from them again.

On the other hand, if in your worker thread you do a non-blocking *connect()* and get notified via epoll_pwait() (or *ppoll()* or *pselect()*; note the *p*), you may be able to avoid race conditions associated with signals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `close()`; I'll look at that. I agree that an event-driven mechanism would be better. However, as I noted in my question, "the `connect()` call is down in some library code that I cannot modify, so changing to a non-blocking socket is not an option."

Comment: The "cannot modify" part should be a big problem here. As I noted, be careful about not closing twice; the library may want to close() it after connect() returns. Have you considered just terminating the process by force when you're done with all of your stuff, making sure the invasive code doesn't misbehave until that point?

Comment: I went with your suggestion to use `shutdown()`. Since the library is written in Python, I can peek in and get access to the underlying socket and subsequently shut it down. It works well. Not the best approach from a software architecture perspective, but it works here, and I do have control over the version of the library that will be used.